# How to install postgresql-8.4?

Tags: 13.04, postgresql

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql
# ... OK

sudo apt-get install postgresql-8.4 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package postgresql-8.4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'postgresql-8.4' has no installation candidate
```

Should I download it from http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/postgresql-8.4 and manually install all the dependencies?

Comment: Try `postgresql-9.2`, there is no 8.4 in this [repo].(https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql/+packages)

Comment: @Manuel, I need strictly 8.4

Answer (score 6):

There is an [repo](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/). To add it, open a terminal and enter

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
sudo echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

Then import the repository signing key:

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you think this `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql` line is doing then?..

Comment: But they seem only to backport new versions, not 8.4. Look at the package list.

Comment: Works for me:
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postgresql-8.4 postgresql-client-8.4

(Yes I realise chances are that was fixed in an edit of the answer)